# cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' in C#

Tags: c#, sum, addition, calculator

I want to make a programs to sum 2 number in 2 text box but it's just not working. I don't know exactly why. (And sorry for my bad english skill XD).

Here's the code :

```
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: What is the value of `textBox1.Text` and `textBox2.Text`? What do you mean by _not working_? Any exception or error message?

Comment: The error should be obvious: the sum is not a String, but an Int32.

Comment: @helb but you can't assign the resulting sum of those two int to a String.

Comment: @crashmstr Yeah, my mistake sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Since the result of the operation is not a string but an int you have to call ToString() to assign the string value to textBox3.Text

```
textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
```

Working code:

```
string y = "";
y = (Convert.ToInt32("3") + Convert.ToInt32("4")).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Int32 value to string for display.

```
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
```